# Div content should not push down div below

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**Edit:** **It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980822/scrollbar-without-fixed-height-dynamic-height-with-scrollbar) solution comes close to what I want, but I want it without declaring a fixed or calculated height. Any way to achieve that?**

Im creating a chat app using React and Chakra-ui. The div containing the chat messages should not push the div with the input below outside the viewport, and it should be scrollable. I have no idea what Im doing wrong as CSS is not my strong suit. I tried giving the parent div `overflow-y: scroll` and a lot of other things but it just doesnt work. Code snippet and screenshots below:

```
<Flex>
  <Sidebar items={[]} />
  <Flex flexDirection="column" w="100%">
    <Header heading={'CHAT'} />
    <Flex direction="column" height="100%" width="100%" pt="1rem">
      <Flex paddingX="1.5rem" direction="column">
        <Message username="User A" body="Test Message 1" time="13:39" />
        <Message username="User B" body="Test Message 2" time="13:40" />
        <Message username="User A" body="Test Message 1" time="13:39" />
        <Message username="User B" body="Test Message 2" time="13:40" />
      </Flex>
      <Flex marginTop="auto" justify="space-between" width="100%">
        <Textarea
          resize="none"
          color="#fff"
          placeholder="Type something..."
          borderTopWidth="1px"
          borderColor="#6b6b6b"
          borderRadius="0px"
          _placeholder={{ color: '#6b6b6b' }}
          paddingY={2}
          paddingX={4}
          variant="unstyled"
        />
        <Flex
          height="100%"
          borderTopWidth="1px"
          borderColor="#6b6b6b"
          px="1rem"
        >
          <Center>
            <IconButton size="sm" isRound icon={<ArrowRightIcon />} />
          </Center>
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  </Flex>
</Flex>
```

[image: bad]

[image: good]

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the 'type something...' bar to stay anchored to the bottom of the view?

Comment: @humans yes thats right! Basically just like any chat app layout, like Telegram for example

Comment: It seems that this solution comes closest to what I want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980822/scrollbar-without-fixed-height-dynamic-height-with-scrollbar

Comment: Sorry I ended up getting tied up at work. Glad you found your solution, you should mark it as accepted when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. [Chakra-ui's Grid component](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/layout/grid) (and css grid in general) is the best way to achieve this what I wanted to achieve:

```
<Grid
  height="100vh"
  templateRows="repeat(15, 1fr)"
  templateColumns="repeat(5, 1fr)"
>
  <GridItem rowSpan={15} colSpan={1}>
    <Sidebar items={state.rooms[ROOM_NAME]?.participants || []} />
  </GridItem>
  <GridItem colSpan={4} rowSpan={1}>
    <Header heading={ROOM_NAME} />
  </GridItem>
  <GridItem colSpan={4} rowSpan={13} overflowY="auto">
    <Flex direction="column">
      <Box paddingX="1.5rem">
        <Message username="User A" body="Test Message 1" time="13:39" />
        <Message username="User B" body="Test Message 2" time="13:40" />
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  </GridItem>
  <GridItem colSpan={4} rowSpan={2}>
    <Flex justify="space-between" width="100%">
      <Textarea
        resize="none"
        color="#fff"
        placeholder="Type something..."
        borderTopWidth="1px"
        borderColor="#6b6b6b"
        borderRadius="0px"
        _placeholder={{ color: '#6b6b6b' }}
        paddingY={2}
        paddingX={4}
        variant="unstyled"
        minHeight={null}
      />
      <Flex borderTopWidth="1px" borderColor="#6b6b6b" px="1rem">
        <Center>
          <IconButton size="sm" isRound icon={<ArrowRightIcon />} />
        </Center>
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  </GridItem>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A pretty common solution to this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462814/6140339)**

> Just set the parent div with position:relative. Then, the inner item you want to stick to the bottom, just use position:absolute to stick it to the bottom of the item.

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: lightblue;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Lorem ipsum.</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ne.</p>
<h2>Lorem ipsum.</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ne.</p>
<h2>Lorem ipsum.</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ne.</p>
<h2>Lorem ipsum.</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ne.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this already... the only difference it makes is that the text area then is on top of the chat messages. I've added more screenshots above.

Comment: @nicolinho66 Ah.. so you want to have an area that has your chat messages in side that scrolls independently?

Comment: yes thats correct. Your solution kind of did help me move forward, but I need that independent scroll of chat messages. The Header needs to keep on top, and the chat input (footer) has to stay below.

Answer (score 0):

You should give `overflow-y: scroll;`  for your Flex in this part then it should scroll instead of pushing to down when it reaches to max height of that element

```
    <Flex paddingX="1.5rem" direction="column">
            <Message username="User A" body="Test Message 1" time="13:39" />
            <Message username="User B" body="Test Message 2" time="13:40" />
            <Message username="User A" body="Test Message 1" time="13:39" />
            <Message username="User B" body="Test Message 2" time="13:40" />
    </Flex>
```

Comment: I tried this already... but some weird scroll bar just appears without the possibility to scroll.  The content still pushes down the text area below.